# How to get count of different types of document in a folder using DQL

Tags: documentum

I have two types of docs say obj_type_A and obj_type_B which may or may not be in a folder of type obj_type_fldr.

I need to get the count of both the docs present in the folder of type obj_type_fldr.

If it had an sql we can write sub-query in select clause. But DQL didn't support this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to utilize the `r_object_type` attribute of `dm_sysobject`. So what you want is probably only achievable if both of your custom types are descendants of `dm_sysobject`. And in that case, this is how you do it.

**Basic count**

```
SELECT count(r_object_id), r_object_type 
FROM dm_sysobject
WHERE ANY i_folder_id IN (
    SELECT r_object_id 
    FROM obj_type_fldr
) 
AND r_object_type IN ('obj_type_A','obj_type_B') 
GROUP BY r_object_type
```

Example output:

```
dm_attr_0001  r_object_type
------------  --------------------------------
         271  obj_type_A
         195  obj_type_B
(2 rows affected)
```

**Count per folder**

Additionally, if you want to count how many documents are in each folder, just add `i_folder_id` to your query like this:

```
SELECT count(r_object_id), r_object_type, i_folder_id 
FROM dm_sysobject
WHERE ANY i_folder_id IN (
    SELECT r_object_id 
    FROM obj_type_fldr
) 
AND r_object_type IN ('obj_type_A','obj_type_B') 
GROUP BY r_object_type, i_folder_id
```

Example output:

```
dm_attr_0001  r_object_type     i_folder_id
------------  ----------------  ----------------
         271  obj_type_A        0b00000080000001
         100  obj_type_B        0b00000080000001
          95  obj_type_B        0b00000080000002
(3 rows affected)
```

You can of course extend this query with additional clauses, e.g. in order to count only documents that are within a specific path, but you get the general idea.

Comment: i thought of the same but I need the output result like     count(obj_type_A),count(obj_Type_B),i_folder_id.  
If i get the result in the above format then which will act like a flag in my code which will make the iteration over millions of data a bit fast.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. Please uprate it as helpful, and mark it as correct.

Comment: the edited query will give me the result like `count,type,i_folder` if I'm not wrong.Lets say I only have two custom type type_A and type_B and I need to get the count of both the document type in a folder.Is it possible to get the count of both a object_type in a single row with there i_folder_id.

So the schema what i want to be in result is `count(type_A),count(type_B),i_folder_id.`

In raw sql this can be done by using subquery in select.

Th

Comment: That's one trickier. Let me think for a moment. And in the meantime, please read the introductory page for stackoverflow about how things work here. My answer is now _correct_ with regards to your question. Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum, it is a place for questions and answers :)

Comment: Hmm new to the community :) . Will upvote the answer. and accept it. 
**I think EMC should have some thing to allow subquery in select clause.**

Comment: Thanks :) I agree with you there. Well I have thought about your question and the only solution is to use a _registered view_ if you would like this as a "one-line answer", and then query this registered view from DQL. Your view needs to pick from both the dm_sysobject_s and dm_sysobject_r tables in your database. The first one contains only one row per ID, the second one (which holds i_folder_id) contains multiple rows per ID. More information here: https://community.emc.com/message/579811

Comment: But views are not updated regularly(only materialized view are updated that too over a period time configured by admin right? ) if i'm not wrong. So in that case there is some probability of getting obsolete data.Right?

Comment: I think you are right. I myself would have used the query suggested in my original answer, and then used code (Java) to sort the output the way I want it. But I am fully aware that this is not always viable.